# How can get Full string from container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search specific string from div and find out whole(full) string

I.e :

```
  <div id='MSO_ContentTable'> 

      [Rotator(Cat=Marketing,Top=5,AutoRotate=true)]

      [Rotator(sg=dummy,Bottom=5,Autosb=true)] 

  blah blah blah .......

  </div>
```

This `div` contains many data but I want to just find full string  only using `Rotator` character in Div content.

```
    $("div[id*='MSO_ContentTable']:contains('[Rotator')").each(function()
    {
       // find out div but not getting full string.
       //.In div also contains another html some thing like
       //<table>,<div> etc. i want to just find string which contain(Rotator)

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can so something like this (you might need to tweak that according to your actual content):

```
var results = new Array();
$("div[id*='MSO_ContentTable']:contains('[Rotator')").each(function(){
   var contents = $(this).text().split(' ');
   $.each(contents,function(){
      var search = /Rotator/;
      if (search.test(this){
      results.push(this);
      }
   });
});
```

See this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnNcz/

Comment: sorry!! you are not getting my question..In div also contains another html some thing like <table>,<div> etc. i want to just find string which `contain(Rotator)`

Comment: @Jigs: There are multiple in your example - which one do you want?

Comment: i want all the string. I mean suppose 5 string contain `[Rotator` so i want only this 5 string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div[id*='MSO_ContentTable']:contains('[Rotator')").each(function() {
    var elements = [];

    $(this).contents().filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3
    }).each(function () {
        elements = elements.concat(this.nodeValue.match(/\[Rotator(.+?)\]/g));
    });

    console.log(elements);
});​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8pPr/1/